Misplaced \noalign while using tabularray
I have the following code:
\documentclass[11pt]{book}
\usepackage[default]{opensans}
\usepackage{tabularray}

\newenvironment{DescCmdStmt}{%
  \begin{center}
    \SetTblrInner{rowsep=10pt}
    \begin{tblr}{|Q[c,m]|Q[c,m]|}
    \end{tblr}
  \end{center}
}

\begin{document}

\begin{DescCmdStmt}
  \hline
  c11 & c12 \\
  c21 & c22 \\
  c31 & c32 \\
  c41 & c42 \\
  c51 & c52 \\
  \hline
\end{DescCmdStmt}

\end{document}

But this code gives me the following error message:
ERROR: Misplaced \noalign.

--- TeX said ---
\hline ->\noalign 
                  {\ifnum 0=`}\fi \hrule \@height \arrayrulewidth \futurelet...l.16   \hline
             
--- HELP ---
From the .log file...

I expect to see \noalign only after the \cr of
an alignment. Proceed, and I'll ignore this case.

I would appreciate it if you would kindly enlighten me about the cause of this problem.

You need to change
\newenvironment{DescCmdStmt}{%
  \begin{center}
    \SetTblrInner{rowsep=10pt}
    \begin{tblr}{|Q[c,m]|Q[c,m]|}
    \end{tblr}
  \end{center}
}

to
\newenvironment{DescCmdStmt}{%
    \begin{center}
    \SetTblrInner{rowsep=10pt}
    \begin{tblr}{|Q[c,m]|Q[c,m]|}}{%
    \end{tblr}
    \end{center}
}


Thank you very much for your help, it worked! But I really don't understand the organization for the curly braces. Why \end{tblr} \end{center} most go to another block between { } ?

@user17911 - A LaTeX environment is not the same as a LaTeX macro. The definition of an environment must provide instructions for what to do both at the start and at the end of the environment. In the case at hand, the 3 start-of-environment commands are \begin{center}, \SetTblrInner{rowsep=10pt}, and \begin{tblr}{|Q[c,m]|Q[c,m]|}, while the 2 end-of-environment commands are \end{tblr} and \end{center}. Plus, there's an implicit \begingroup statement at the very start and an implicit \endgroup at the very end of the environment. Does this help?

Thank you very much. I didn't know this. I just found the following page: https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Environments which presents the general syntax (as you said): \newenvironment{name}[numarg][optarg_default]{begin_def}{end_def}. Thank you very much for your time and your help.
